# IE9 Webpage shows white patches

Tags: css, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, html

I have a weird problem, one of the user who uses our system using windows 7 and IE 9 browsers.
When the user open one of the webpage the page comes like this.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is it supposed to look, and can you add the minimal amount of code to replicate the issue?

Comment: Please read the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines.

Comment: I may not be able to add code here, the problem is the web page shows all labels and text boxes properly in chrome. But in IE the page displays like above with white area and when user moves the mouse it comes up. I feel there is something this problem with graphics setting or screen refresh rate.

Comment: This works in chrome very well. I feel something to do with Graphics settings in IE. I am not very sure